# postgres query explanation

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql

I am making an App where there are message boards and for each board, there is a number of threads and for each thread, there is a number of replies

I need to make a query that gets the threads of a specific board (by board_id) and within each thread, an array of it's replies if no replies for the thread then, get it with an empty replies array

I am not sure if it can be done by a pg query, and it might be achieved by a simple code in the backend modifying the data coming from the query to the format I like but I find a solution currently

here are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE threads (
    _id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    board_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES board(id),
    text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    delete_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    reported  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    created_on DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    bumped_on DATE  DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);


CREATE TABLE board (
    _id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE replies (
   _id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   thread_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES threads(id),
   text VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   delete_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   reported  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
   created_on DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `array`? PostgreSQL array? So you'll get that many records as you get `threads` for a given board?

Comment: Can you share with us queries that didn't work for you?

Comment: @anatoly I mean that I need to get a response like this one  : threads: {id, text, ...etc, replies = [array of replies] } Do you think this can be achieved with a simple trick in the backed and no need for a so complex query if so, I would like you to point me out to that trick

Comment: @Anatoly My main problem was that for each thread I need to get the replies so, I thought of looping over threads and for each thread a query is made to get the replies but that's not efficient at all

Comment: So you need `replies` field as JSON?

Comment: exactly exactly